# why init() user service method did not sumbit a user in mysql when starting the server and after index.jsp opens?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements  UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void init(){
          // i called this code in controller in index method
        AppUsers user = new AppUsers();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("alice");
        user.setLastname("brown");
        user.setEmail("example@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("123456");
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }}
```

Comment: this is a simple of my controller where it calls for init method , the problem here is that each time i start the server the table in my database is initialized as an empty table even each time i add manuall in phpmyAdmin a user example , the exemple is gone after i restart server

Comment: here is my controller code having the block of init method
 please 
note that
 i add "//" each time before the annotation just to make my comment appear , but in my code i have right written annotations //@Controller public class HomeController { //@Autowired UserService userService; //@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET) // @ResponseBody public String Hello() { userService.init(); return "index"; } –

Comment: version are spring 5 , hibernate 5.xx and most importantly intellij idea ultimate 2018.3.3